# Does the adverb "proprement" give rise to the same issue as the widespread misuse of "literally" in English?

Tags: usage

In English, the widespread *misuse* of the adverb "literally" to emphasise an idea is a controversial topic:

> This building is like **literally** 1000 years old.

I wonder if the same issue arises from the French adverb "proprement":

> Les motifs sur les murs sont **proprement** fascinants, tu ne trouves pas ?

Comment: Not with *“proprement”*, as stated by the answers so far, but other adverbs are sometimes used in a controversial way. [Here is an example](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3425) from the OQLF with *extrêmement* and *excessivement*. [Another nice discussion](https://rouleaum.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/adverbes-en-ment-5-de-5/) about *présentement* and *possiblement* in Quebec’s usage.

Answer (score 4):

What makes you believe that *proprement* is misused in this sentence? It means that the patterns are especially fascinating in a way that other things aren't. In brief, *d'une manière qui leur est **propre*** (sorry, this cannot be translated without losing the effect I want to give it). [One definition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/proprement) of *proprement* is:

> D'une manière qui est spéciale, spécifique à une personne, à un ensemble de personnes, à une chose.

It's a perfectly good use of the word.

Answer (score 2):

"Proprement" is really too posh in French (of France) to be an equivalent of "literally". The closest term I can think of is "carrément" which we use a lot, though it never became a thing in France (maybe in other French-speaking countries?).

Comment: agreed. "carrément" is used quite a lot by teenagers (at least when I was one, about 6-7 years ago), but it stayed very colloquial/familiar french (in France at least)

Comment: *Carrément méchant, jamais content* (Alain Souchon 1977), *Un homme à la hauteur de son temps et carrément dégagé des préjugés d'honneur (E. et J. de Goncourt, Journal,1861)*

Answer (score 1):

Using *proprement* to emphasize an idea is not controversial in French. One of the meanings of *[proprement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/proprement)* in the TLFi is:

> **I.- C.-** − [Dans un sens affaibli, vient renforcer une affirm.] Synon. de absolument, totalement.

Answer (score 1):

As said, it's theoretically right to say to use *proprement* in the meaning of *d'une manière qui leur est propre*. The thing is that in practice I've never heard anyone using this adverb to emphasize an adjective, not even misused. People tend to misuse *littéralement* sometimes, although less often than the English with *litteraly*. If you used *proprement* in that context, you would sound as if translating litteraly from English to French.

Actually the main reason for it is that the first meaning of *propre* is *clean*. *Proprement* means on a clean way like 'Mange *proprement*' as a parent would say to his child.
Though in some widespread expressions as 'Proprement dit' or 'À proprement parler', it doesn't mean clean at all, but rather *properly*.